# How do I set a session token for a client in aws-sdk for Go version 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an aws_session_token in my `~/.aws/credentials file`.  I read it like this using the aws-sdk for Go version 2:

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-west-2"), config.WithSharedConfigProfile("devadm"))  
...   
retrieve, err := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(context.TODO())
...
token := retrieve.SessionToken
```

How do I set this token in a client for dynamodb, s3, or kms?  There is nothing in the docs about this for version 2 of the aws-sdk for Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't ever need to touch the session token (which by the way may change with time in some circumstances).

All you have to do is create your dynamo, etc client with the config you created.

[From the github readme](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2#write-code):

```
    // Using the Config value, create the DynamoDB client
    svc := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

Comment: You're correct.  I was getting an error saying the token was expired, which I took to mean that I had not set the token in the request.  It turns out that the session token I had in my .aws/credentials file was expired.  Once I refreshed that it worked.

Comment: good point.  I should have picked up on that.  You shouldn't have to put the session token in the file.  If you're using SSO that should work falwlessly with the Go SDK.  Assumed roles should as well.  So I suspect there's a better workflow,because session token will _always_ expire soon